# How to automatically delete Test Results

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I run tests several times a day in Visual Studio 2012. I recently found that my disk space was very low. I found that the test results folder in my project was using 60 GB. I deleted the files, but I want to keep it from happening. I did a search for how to do this, but all I can find are solutions for 2008 and 2010. They stated I need to make some changes to the test tools in the options. I can't find this inside of my options. How can I keep from these files appearing, or keep them to a minimal?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 14):

Mark Seemann [suggests extending the Clean target](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2006/07/13/cleaningawaythetestresultsfolder.aspx)

Add this after the *Import* element at the end of the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TestResultsFolderPath>..\TestResults</TestResultsFolderPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="AfterClean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(TestResultsFolderPath)" Condition="Exists('$(TestResultsFolderPath)')" />
</Target>
```

Then whenever you want to manually remove the test results, you can just right-click in the Solution explorer and select *Clean*.

You can also achieve the same from the command line with the following

```
MSBuild /t:Clean MyProject.csproj
```

which can be scheduled if you want an automatic deletion once a week or whatever. As Mark points out, one nice feature of this approach is that you can control the deletion on a project by project basis.